# Number of classes of graphs consisting of 8 vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Problem: Prove that there's more than 6600 different classes of isomorphism of simple graphs with 8 vertices.

I really have no clue how to solve this.

I thought of counting how many edges can be in such graph (which is in an interval $\left<0, \binom{8}{2}\right>$.

Then I've tried to count the number of ways to put those edges in my graph. That should be equal to $\sum_{i=0}^{28}\binom{8}{2}^{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{28}28^{i}$

But that's where I've stopped because this counting lets me have more than one edge between two vertices, and I can't have that. Basically, my logic was wrong.

Any hints or comments are welcome!

Comment: I'd say, take a look at OEIS and see what 6600 counts that may be (in bijection with) a subset of what you're counting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here’s a hint. The size of an isomorphism class is at most 8! and there are $2^\binom{8}2 = 2^{28}$ graphs with vertex set $\{1,\ldots,8\}$. So there are at least $2^{28}/8!$ isomorphism classes.